# Laravel: Passport API with accept image

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

So I have already a working `api` using `laravel passport`

in my `controller` named as `AuthController.php`

I have this working code of saving data

```
    public function activity_log(Request $request){

    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'projCode'=>'required',
        'activity_desc'=>'required',
        'type'=>'required'
    ]);

    $tbl_projectlist = DB::connection('mysql')->select("SELECT * from tbl_projectlist WHERE proj_code = '".$request->projCode."'");

    if(empty($tbl_projectlist))
    {
        return response([
            "status"=>"bad",
            "message"=>"Invalid projCode doesn't exists."
        ]);
    }
    else if($request->type == "REPORT" || $request->type == "ISSUE")
    {
        $ActivityLog = new ActivityLog;
        $ActivityLog->projCode = $request->projCode;
        $ActivityLog->activity_desc = $request->activity_desc;
        $ActivityLog->type = $request->type;
        $ActivityLog->attachment = "/img/default-image.jpg";
        $ActivityLog->created_by_id = Auth::user()->company_id;
        $ActivityLog->created_by_name = Auth::user()->name;
        $ActivityLog->created_at = now();
        $ActivityLog->updated_at = now();
        $ActivityLog->save();

        return response([
            "status"=>"ok",
            "message"=>"Activity successfully submitted!"
        ]);
    }
    else
    {
        return response([
            "status"=>"bad",
            "message"=>"Invalid choose REPORT or ISSUE"
        ]);
    }

}
```

and in my `api.php`

```
Route::post('/login','Auth\Api\AuthController@login');

Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {

     Some routes...

     Route::post('/activity_log','Auth\Api\AuthController@activity_log');
});
```

As of now i'm just storing the file path of the image `hard coded` which the img is located.

What I'm trying to do is to accept img file and save to my folder and store the file path in my database

I'm using postman to test my api with this

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: What's your frontend framework ?

Comment: api for upload img will be used by the mobile app. Mobile app still on the planning process. My api only runs backend only the app will use the api

Comment: I suggest using a form as action is link with controller to upload the image in backend's server

Comment: what do you mean with your suggestion? `http://192.168.0.35:905/api/activity_log` this link is just a backend only.

Comment: no like make a get route (web.php) , like get /upload_image linked to controller i.e : ImageController@upload, and make a form to upload image, <form action="http://192.168.0.35:905/upload_image" method="get"> Here a input upload image </form>

Comment: Or you can use Dropzone.js where you make js function for a form submitter

Comment: How will the other sites or mobile app will use the api with that kind of approach? hmmm is it possible to upload the image using backend only with that kind of approach? as I shown above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From postman: use POST method, select body and form-data, select file and use image as key after that select file from value which you need to upload.

```
public function uploadTest(Request $request) {

    if(!$request->hasFile('image')) {
        return response()->json(['upload_file_not_found'], 400);
    }
    $file = $request->file('image');
    if(!$file->isValid()) {
        return response()->json(['invalid_file_upload'], 400);
    }
    $path = public_path() . '/uploads/images/store/';
    $file->move($path, $file->getClientOriginalName());
    return response()->json(compact('path'));
 }
```

Comment: how do you validate this if file sent is not image?

Comment: use this as validateur $this->validate($request, ['file' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',]);